# PHPMailer does not send mail to group email

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am able to send emails to individual email ids using PHPMailer.

But, I am not able to send email to group email using PHPMailer. I am not talking about sending multiple emails using loop.

Suppose, I have an email group@example.com and this is a group email. That means, if we send email to this, it will be received by all the people added to this email group.

I tried sending email to group email but no one received the email. I am using same domain sender email id. For ex: noreply@example.com

My code looks like below

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->From     = 'noreply@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'FromName';
$mail->Subject  = 'Subject';
$mail->Body     = 'Body';
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->AddAttachment($file);
$mail->AddAddress($groupEmail);
if(!$mail->send()){
    //error msg
}
```

Comment: First check their junk mails

Comment: Debug the php mailer `$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;`  and the php script. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: `SMTPDebug` won't help as PHPmailer sends via the `mail()` function by default. Look in your mail server logs. PHPMailer can't tell than an address is a group address - that all happens long after it has finished its job.

Comment: Try to create a email account for the FROM address and then send

Comment: Thanks @Synchro I checked the mail server logs and the issue was not related to PHPMailer. There was some other internal mail issue.